# How to insert multiple rows in same SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run this Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)
VALUES ((001, 002), ("f", "Doe"), ("f", "John"), ("6256 german Ave S", "1234 random ave"), ("berlin", "Rondomville"))
```

and get this error:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I don't know what exactly i'm doing wrong here.

If I run the Statement below everthing works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)
VALUES(001, "f", "a", "6254 german Ave S", "berlin")
```

Comment: Group the values by rows, not by columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax for this is:

```
INSERT INTO Persons 
            (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)
VALUES      (1, 'f', 'f', '6256 german Ave S', 'berlin'),
            (2, 'Doe', 'John', '1234 random ave', 'Rondomville')
```

Alternatively, you can do a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO         Persons 
                    (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)
SELECT              1, 'f', 'f', '6256 german Ave S', 'berlin'
UNION ALL SELECT    2, 'Doe', 'John', '1234 random ave', 'Rondomville'
```

Comment: Your alternate answer looks a lot like my answer.   Just sayin'

Comment: It's a very common query to use. Just sayin'.

Comment: Thanks, it's always the simple errors that cause the most frustration

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Address, City)
Select 001, "f", "a", "6254 german Ave S", "berlin"
UNION ALL
Select 002, "f", "a", "333 deutch strasse", "freiburg"
```

Comment: The reason I prefer this over the "values" way...is that I can select just the "select" portion of the code and run it.  In a stored procedure, I could temporarily comment out the "insert" part and get the select query to run.  You cannot do that with the "values" syntax.